# Does VoltDB's Connector Sink support Avro messages?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, voltdb

Does VoltDB's Kafka connector support reading avro messages Below is my attempt to configure the connector ?

```
{
   "name":"KafkaSinkConnector",
   "config":{
      "connector.class":"org.voltdb.connect.kafka.KafkaSinkConnector",
      "tasks.max":"1",
      "voltdb.servers":"node1:21212,node2:21212,node3:21212",
      "voltdb.procedure":"USER.insert",
      "voltdb.connection.user":"test",
      "voltdb.connection.password":"test",
      "topics":"user",
      "key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
      "key.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://kafka-schema-registry:8081",
      "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
      "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://kafka-schema-registry:8081",
      "key.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
      "value.converter.schemas.enable":"true", 
   }
}
```

The connector loads with no error messages are displayed but nothing is written to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, neither the Kafka importer nor the sink connector currently support Avro messages. This is a good feature request that could be added in the future, however.

Full disclosure: I work for VoltDB.

-Andrew